# Including application specific header files in static libraries, in a multi-application CMake project

Tags: c, cmake

We have a repository, where the code is structured in a similar way as below (minimal example):

```
CMakeExample
├── Apps
│   ├── App1
│   │   ├── AppSpecificHeader.h
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── main.c
│   ├── App2
│   │   ├── AppSpecificHeader.h
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── main.c
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── Libs
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Lib1
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── Lib1.c
    │   └── Lib1.h
    └── Lib2
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── Lib2.c
        └── Lib2.h
```

In a single CMake project, we build several static libraries and several applications that make use of the libraries.

The problem is that some of the static libraries depend on header files that are application specific. Meaning that App1 want a version of Lib1 where Lib1.c has been compiled with an include of its AppSpecificHeader, while App2 wants a version of Lib1 which has been compiled with App2's version of the AppSpecificHeader.

Of course Lib2 might also depend on Lib1, which could further complicate things(?).

What we have done so far is to not build Lib1 as a lib at all, but rather include a file Lib1.cmake, in each application, so that Lib1 is built as part of the respective application. But of course, if Lib2 depends on Lib1, it also has to be compiled as part of the application as well, even though it does not depend directly on the application specific header file.

This workaround works fairly well, but as I understand this is quite bad practice. However, we can't seem to find a CMake mechanism to accommodate what we want, using "modern" CMake.

We've explored the possibility of creating an interface library that only includes the AppSpecificHeader, and make Lib1 dependent on that, however that came to a dead end, when trying to create two interface libs with the same name in each respective application.

We have also considered adding a flag that specifies the application we want to build. However, that would lead to having to build several times, and longer compile times.

Have we encountered a limitation of CMake?

Any inputs on solutions or improvements to this would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Apps/App1/AppSpecificHeader.h

```
#ifndef APP_SPECIFIC_HEADER_H
#define APP_SPECIFIC_HEADER_H

#define CONSTANT_CONFIG_VALUE 5U

#endif
```

Apps/App2/AppSpecificHeader.h

```
#ifndef APP_SPECIFIC_HEADER_H
#define APP_SPECIFIC_HEADER_H

#define CONSTANT_CONFIG_VALUE 6U

#endif
```

Libs/Lib1/Lib1.c

```
#include "Lib1.h"
#include "AppSpecificHeader.h"

void foo()
{

    uint8_t val = CONSTANT_CONFIG_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This is a result of a proprietary tool, that generates a configuration and an object dictionary for a bought CanOpen stack. For the definitions of the object dictionary you make a really good point which I hadn't considered and will look into. However, a couple of the generated header files contains strictly macros of which the CanOpen stack depends.

Comment: No worries, just a misunderstanding. I've updated the example now to show a bit more of the issue. You're right, its only the implementation of the Lib1 in this case that depends on the application specific header file. And we use the tool to generate two different header files for the two different applications. Ideally I would be able to tell CMake to compile two different versions of Lib1, one for each application to depend on, inside a single CMake project, but that's maybe not possible?

Comment: a whole lot of things are possible. It often comes down to what is necessary, and then what you _want_ to do (I'd assume you want to do something that scores well in simplicity and cleanness).

Answer (score 0):

The library you've shown is defining a struct using a macro value from an application-specific header for a member's default initialization. I'd consider the following options.

- You could see if you can declare a default constructor in the library, and only implement it in the applications that does that default initialization. In this case, the libraries would never `#include` the application-specific headers or use their macros- the applications would to implement the default constructors of those libraries' structs.

  Or if that doesn't work, see if you're willing to require a (ew) manual initialization function that is declared in the library and defined in the applications.
- There's a very very very slim chance you can move the definition of the struct entirely into the application itself, and only use forward declarations of that struct in the library.
- You could probably- as you say- create as many versions of that library as the number of applications you have. With such an approach, it would be useful to put those application-specific headers each in their own [interface library target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries), and then define each of your other libraries also as interface libraries, and then create actual (static/shared) library targets each link to a application-specific header interface library target, and a non-application-specific interface library target. The nice thing about this approach is that in the two-level `foreach` loop (one level for application-specific interface targets, one level for non-application-specific interface targets) you'd use to create the actual library targets, it would be pretty simple: `add_library`, and two `target_link_libraries`.

  Or you could look at a CMake approach where instead of interface targets, you do most of the work inside the two-level `foreach` loop.